# Is the categorical variable relevant if one of the dummy variable has a t score of 0.95?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

If a variable has more than 0.05 t score, it is deemed not relevant and should be excluded from the model. However, what if the categorical variable has 4 dummy variable and only one of them exceeds 0.05? Do i exclude the entire categorical variable?

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:              SalePrice   R-squared:                       0.803
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.801
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     368.4
Date:                Mon, 15 Jul 2019   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        12:00:26   Log-Likelihood:                -17357.
No. Observations:                1460   AIC:                         3.475e+04
Df Residuals:                    1443   BIC:                         3.484e+04
Df Model:                          16                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
============================================================================================
                               coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const                    -1.366e+05   9432.229    -14.482      0.000   -1.55e+05   -1.18e+05
OverallQual               1.327e+04   1249.192     10.622      0.000    1.08e+04    1.57e+04
ExterQual                 1.168e+04   2763.188      4.228      0.000    6262.969    1.71e+04
TotalBsmtSF                 13.7198      5.182      2.648      0.008       3.554      23.885
GrLivArea                   45.4098      2.521     18.012      0.000      40.465      50.355
1stFlrSF                     9.4573      5.543      1.706      0.088      -1.416      20.330
GarageArea                  22.4791      9.748      2.306      0.021       3.358      41.600
KitchenQual               1.309e+04   2142.662      6.111      0.000    8891.243    1.73e+04
GarageCars                8875.8202   2961.291      2.997      0.003    3066.923    1.47e+04
BsmtQual                  1.097e+04   2094.395      5.235      0.000    6856.671    1.51e+04
GarageFinish_No           2689.1356   5847.186      0.460      0.646   -8780.759    1.42e+04
GarageFinish_RFn         -8223.4503   2639.360     -3.116      0.002   -1.34e+04   -3046.057
GarageFinish_Unf         -8416.9443   2928.002     -2.875      0.004   -1.42e+04   -2673.349
BsmtExposure_Gd           2.298e+04   3970.691      5.788      0.000    1.52e+04    3.08e+04
BsmtExposure_Mn           -262.8498   4160.294     -0.063      0.950   -8423.721    7898.021
BsmtExposure_No          -7690.0994   2800.731     -2.746      0.006   -1.32e+04   -2196.159
BsmtExposure_No Basement  2.598e+04   9879.662      2.630      0.009    6598.642    4.54e+04
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                      614.604   Durbin-Watson:                   1.972
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):            76480.899
Skew:                          -0.928   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Kurtosis:                      38.409   Cond. No.                     2.85e+04
==============================================================================
```

Comment: note that https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better forum for these sorts of questions (i.e. stats questions with no code)

Answer (score 1):

when you say "0.05 t score" I assume you mean "0.05 p value".  the t-value is just `coef / stderr`, which goes into the p-value calculation (`abs(t_value) > 2` is approximately p-value < 0.05)

when you say "categorical variable has 4 dummy variable", I presume you mean it has 4 "levels" / distinct values and you're referring to `BsmtExposure_Mn`.  I'd leave that in as the other categories/levels are helping the model.  if you had several categories that were less predictive you could think about combining them into one "other" category

as a general point, you shouldn't just automatically exclude variables because their p-value is > 0.05 (or whatever your cutoff/"alpha value" is).  they can be useful for understanding what's going on within the model, and explaining results to other people